# How to integrate ready database into new installed mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I need to configure and run ready web site. I installed apache and configured it.Now frontend of the web site works great. I need to configure the backend also. They used mssql 2005 and also sent me the database. I installed the express version of the mssql 2005, and now I don't know how to integrate ready database to the new installed mssql.
Please help me to find out.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just try to describe the situation. Maybe because of my english i did something wrong, but instead of closing my question, you could help me. Was it hard to ask me more, if you didn't understand a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database file are you trying to use?  A SQL "BACKUP" of the original database or a detached database you want to reattach to your database server?

Instructions to reattach a MS SQL 2005 database: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209(v=SQL.90).aspx

Instructions to restore a MS SQL 2005 database from a backup file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: thanks so much, sorry for bad described question. I mean instructions to restore a MS SQL 2005 database from a backup file. Thanks again